# Struggling with sub arrays

Tags: ruby

I have an array (a nested array to be more precise), like this:

```
[["Armando", "P"], ["Dave", "S"], ["Richard", "R"], ["Michael", "S"], 
["Allen", "S"], ["Omer", "P"], ["David E.", "R"], ["Richard X.", "P"]]
```

I want to pass two tuples at a time as the parameters to another function, like:

```
rps_result(["Armando", "P"], ["Dave", "S"])
rps_result(["Richard", "R"], ["Michael", "S"])
```

I am trying do this as I loop through my array:

```
arr.each_slice(2) do |first, second|  
  rps_game_winner([first, second])
end
```

However, this does not give the desired answer when I print them the values of the arguments. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You describe how to use `rps_result`, but that is irrelevant to the rest of the question, and you do not show how to use `rps_game_winner` or how many arguments it takes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove square brackets over arguments:

```
arr.each_slice(2) { |first, second| fun(first, second) }
```